# Можно ли прятать контент(страницу, пункт меню) для не зарегистрированных пользователей?

Tags: wordpress

Всем привет!Хочу сделать так чтобы контент на странице или отдельный пункт меню могли видеть только зарегистрированные пользователи. Может кто с таким сталкивался сайт, на wordpress?

1.Вот эту страницу https://www.desiweds.com/vendors-list/ , мне нужно показывать только зарегистрированным.

2.Этот пункт в меню http://joxi.ru/MAjyx3OCxozOY2 как на скрине тоже нужно показывать только тем кто залогинился на сайте.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [is_user_logged_in()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/), которая вернёт `true` в случае, если пользователь залогинен, и `false`, если это гость.

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
    // выполняем код для зарегистрированного и залогиненного пользователя
} else {
    // выполняем действия для гостя
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Все можно проверить через ф-цию `current_user_can( 'capability' )`, где нужные capability вы можете посмотреть здесь: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/.

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    ...
}
```

Так же если вы используете add_menu_page

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_my_custom_menu_page' );
function register_my_custom_menu_page(){
    add_menu_page( 
        'custom menu title',
        'custom menu',
        'manage_options', // Нужные права
        'custompage'
    ); 
}
```